# Shuffle an array with a consistent order, based on today's date - Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, date, shuffle

I want to shuffle an array of `Any` objects, but the order should remain consistent any time I perform the shuffle during the current calendar day.

```
let myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(myArray.myShuffleForDateFunction(Date()))

//output today is always e.g. [3, 5, 1, 2, 4] 
//output tomorrow is always e.g. [1, 4, 5, 3, 2], etc
```

So want some random order generator that I seed with today's date, e.g.

```
let todayAtMidnight = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())
let secondsSince1970UntilTodayAtMidnight = todayAtMidnight.timeIntervalSince1970
```

I've looked at `shuffle(using:)`, but can I pass it a generator seeded with my date, or is there something else I can use?

Comment: Why not shuffle once and then if you've shuffled that day, don't shuffle again? Or do you mean that everyone in the world who shuffles on that day should get the same order, like a kind of one-time pad?

Comment: @matt I want to use this logic for several arrays within the app, so don't want to keep track of 'hasBeenShuffledToday' state for each

Comment: @matt, interesting that you bring up the everyone-in-the-world-gets-the-same idea, as I don't necessarily require that, but it would make analytics more powerful if I could retrospectively generate the sort order based on dates.

Comment: "I want to use this logic for several arrays within the app, so don't want to keep track of 'hasBeenShuffledToday' state for each" That sounds like a perfect use case for a property wrapper.

Comment: Thanks @sweeper, I'll look into that too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

I looked up how to seed random number generators and found this topic:
[Generating random numbers in swift](https://theswiftdev.com/generating-random-numbers-in-swift/)

Using your technique to get todays midnight date as a number... you can seed the number generator and get the same random sequence per midnight date.

```
import GameplayKit

let myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

let calendar = Calendar.current
let todayAtMidnight = calendar.startOfDay(for: Date())
let seed = UInt64(todayAtMidnight.timeIntervalSince1970)

var mersenneTwister = GKMersenneTwisterRandomSource(seed: seed)
let fixedArrayByDate = mersenneTwister.arrayByShufflingObjects(in: myArray)
print(fixedArrayByDate)
```

This prints out for today's date:

```
[2, 3, 4, 1, 5]
```

---

As suggested by Daniel, one could set up an extension for fun:

```
import GameplayKit

extension Array {
    func shuffledByDate(_ date: Date) -> [Any] {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let todayAtMidnight = calendar.startOfDay(for: date)
        let seed = UInt64(todayAtMidnight.timeIntervalSince1970)
        
        let mersenneTwister = GKMersenneTwisterRandomSource(seed: seed)
        return mersenneTwister.arrayByShufflingObjects(in: self)
    }
}

let myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].shuffledByDate(Date())
print(myArray)
```

Comment: For extra fun you could wrap this in an extension `func shuffledByDate()` or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for this Gabriel. I used `GKLinearCongruentialRandomSource` instead of `GKMersenneTwisterRandomSource`, because I preferred execution speed over quality randomness. Cheers